# Hbase client creates thousands of connections to single server

Tags: hadoop, hbase

We are running HBase 0.94.2 and Hadoop 1.1.2 in fully distributed mode with one master and one slave server. The HBase server has 7 tables.

We have a Hadoop job which writes and reads from the HBase tables. It seems like the HBase client creates a new connection to the region server for every operation. While one task is running there is more than 10 000 connections to the region server. A large majority are in TIME_WAIT but this soon leads problems creating more connections when there are multiple tasks running at the same time.

The one task also has > 500 threads with the name "IPC Client (47) connection to /10.4.8.101:60020 from root"

We do use HbaseSynchronizationManager.bindResource to bind the tables to the thread.

Any ideas on why this may be happening will be very helpful!

thanks

UPDATE 1

We use spring to create a Configuration and HbaseTemplate like so

```
<hdp:hbase-configuration id="hbaseConfiguration" properties-location="classpath:hbase.properties"/>
<bean id="hbaseTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate" p:configuration-ref="hbaseConfiguration"/>
```

From here will use the HbaseTemplate to execute a Put etc.
All the spring configuration happens in the setup of the Mapper.

Comment: How does your Hadoop job read from and write to HBase?

Answer (score 0):

I found various issues in the Hbase jira which described similar issues. They were fixed in 0.94.7. After I upgraded to a newer version in the 0.94.x series the issue was resolved.